# Getting a part from the page URL

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

I have a url:

http://example.com/lobby/5 (5 could be any number).

How can I get the 5 part to a JS var?

The link is the page url, not user submitted.

I had this function that worked when the link was http://example.com/lobby.php?id=5

```
function getQueryParam(param) {
  location.search.substr(1).split("&").some(function(item) { // returns first occurence and stops
      return item.split("=")[0] == param && (param = item.split("=")[1])
    })
  return param;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use regular expressions

```js
var link = "http://example.com/lobby.php?id=5";
var numb = link.match(/\=([^=/]+)\/?$/)[1];
console.log(numb) // 5

var link1 = "http://example.com/lobby/55";
var numb1 = link1.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
console.log(numb1) // 55
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.location.search.match(/[0-9]+/);
```

To get any number from url.